Select columns from union tables
I have 4 diff tables as below:

Table columns are as below:

Need to select all columns from all the 4 tables.
I am able to select AMOUNT and RETAIL columns, but not able to figure out the way to select CA_XXXX_CA_APPLE_ID column.
Code tried so far:
 Select ' Select AMOUT,RETAIL'+
           ' from '+TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+ table_name +
         ' Union All'
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE  'CA_%_APPLE';

It gives me below:
 Select AMOUT,RETAIL from data.CA_2003_CA_APPLE Union All
 Select AMOUT,RETAIL from data.CA_2004_CA_APPLE Union All
 Select AMOUT,RETAIL from data.CA_2005_CA_APPLE Union All
 Select AMOUT,RETAIL from data.CA_2006_CA_APPLE Union All

Desired Output:
 Select CA_2003_CA_APPLE_ID,AMOUT,RETAIL from data.CA_2003_CA_APPLE Union All
 Select CA_2004_CA_APPLE_ID,AMOUT,RETAIL from data.CA_2004_CA_APPLE Union All
 Select CA_2005_CA_APPLE_ID,AMOUT,RETAIL from data.CA_2005_CA_APPLE Union All
 Select CA_2006_CA_APPLE_ID,AMOUT,RETAIL from data.CA_2006_CA_APPLE Union All

is it even possible what I am trying to achieve?
Thanks

Yes, but why bother if you only have 4 tables? Names containing numbers is sign of bad design too, you should fix that. For your general issue, you can check out sys.tables and sys.columns instead of INFORMATION_SCHEMA stuff

There are way more tables since 1990 till date, I have mentioned only 4 in my example.

Perhaps: Select ' Select ' + table_name  + '_ID, AMOUT,RETAIL'+            ' from '+TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+ table_name +          ' Union All' From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE  'CA_%_APPLE';

Please don't use images, use table markdown

in a union the column names are acquired from the first select , so you might as well alias id's to something generic and add a source column to indicate where the row came from.

Usually it's not recommended to have numeric year in the table name. Depending on what the application is trying to achieve, the data modeling can be structured differently. If you have to work with the data structure in question, I guess how about the 2 queries below?
Option (1):
-- This assume the ID column is just table name appended with "_ID".
SELECT 'SELECT ' + TABLE_NAME  + '_ID, AMOUT, RETAIL '+
       'FROM ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' UNION All'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE  'CA_%_APPLE';

Option (2):
-- This assumes that ID column is always the first (left most) column.
SELECT 'SELECT ' + Col.COLUMN_NAME  + ', AMOUT, RETAIL '+
       'FROM ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' UNION All'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS Tbl
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS Col ON
    Col.TABLE_CATALOG = Tbl.TABLE_CATALOG
        AND Col.TABLE_SCHEMA = Tbl.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND Col.TABLE_NAME = Tbl.TABLE_NAME
        AND Col.ORDINAL_POSITION = 1
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE  'CA_%_APPLE';

